# Socket only works when firewall turned off

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I have a simple client-server script setup which allows me to send a message from my android device to my computer. The computer server script is something like this -

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(9000);
Socket socket = server.accept();
//read from socket to ObjectInputStream object
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
//convert objectinputstream to string
String message = (String)ois.readObject();
System.out.println("Message received: " + message);
ois.close();
socket.close();
```

And the android code is something like this (Note that this code runs as a async task) -

```
socket = new Socket( "10.69.23.11",9000);
//write to socket using Objectouputstream

oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

oos.writeObject(msg);

oos.close();
```

This code works and I tested it a few weeks ago. But starting from last week after I upgraded from java 1.7 to 1.8, this code no longer works. If I turn my firewall completely off this code starts working again. I explicitly added inbound and outbound rules to let port 9000 through as a tcp but it still doesn't work with the firewall on. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: what do you mean by it's not working? is it like, there is an error? if so, then could you post the stack trace? or is it just hang and not doing anything when you run it?

Comment: **"...this code no longer works."** - That doesn't really help us to identify what your problem is. At which point is it not working? Do you see the "Message received: " message at the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out firewall was somehow blocking my eclipse. I went into windows control panel and let microsoft diagnose me a solution. Never expected it but they correctly identified it and fixed the problem automatically by bypassing firewall for eclipse.